# Properly resize an Azure VM disk

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk, azure

I just resized a disk attached to a Linux VM (Ubuntu 18.04) on Azure, using the portal. Do I have to re-partition it now?

I deallocated the machine and set the disk size to 200 Gb in the "Configuration" box, then re-booted it.  On the portal, the disk size now shows as 200 Gb.  But when I run `df -h` on the VM, it still shows the disk's original size of 100 Gb ('/dev/sdb1', below).

I'm pretty ignorant about Linux disks and I don't know what Azure will take care of by default.

Thanks!

```
$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   28G     0   28G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.5G  1.2M  5.5G   1% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4       97G   32G   66G  33% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      28G  8.0K   28G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs      28G     0   28G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs   40M   40M     0 100% /snap/hub/43
/dev/loop1     squashfs   94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop2     squashfs   13M   13M     0 100% /snap/hub/29
/dev/loop3     squashfs   98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/9289
/dev/sdb1      ext4       99G   96G     0 100% /data
/dev/sdc1      ext4     1007G  792G  164G  83% /cdata
/dev/sdd1      ext4      334G   69M  317G   1% /mnt
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.5G   28K  5.5G   1% /run/user/113
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.5G     0  5.5G   0% /run/user/1003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer; first a couple of key points:

- OS disks on Azure VMs are automatically re-partitioned when they are resized
- Other disks including the default `/data` disk that comes with a DSVM are **not** automatically re-partioned, so once you've resized a data disk, you have to re-partition it to use the space you created.
- A **warning** that your home directory is probably on /data; therefore by un-mounting the disk in the first step of the instructions, you can lock yourself out of SSH (as I did) if you have disabled password access and your private SSH key is in the `~/.ssh/` directory, as it probably is.  If that happens, you can get back in through the Azure portal (find your VM, look near the bottom of the sidebar under Support and Troubleshooting —> Reset Password, then check “Configuration Only”, then "Update".)

The rest of the process is explained quite well in [these Azure docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/expand-disks).  They expect you to know is that the disk itself is probably called something like `/dev/sba` and any partitions on it will have the same name with a number added (for example `/dev/sba1`, `/dev/sba2`), and so on.  Warning: these names are assigned asynchronously, and they can change if you restart your VM.

For people in a hurry, the procedure to resize the existing partition is:

```bsh
#Find the name of your disk:  
df -Th 

#Unmount the disk (in this example it's "sdc1")  
sudo umount /dev/sdc1  

#Call the interactive 'parted' command  
sudo parted /dev/sdc
   #1. Type "print" and note the size of the disk
   #2. Type "resizepart"
   #      A. Type the partition number
   #      B. Type the size from the "print" command to make a full-size partition
   #3. Type "quit" to exit

#Clean up any errors and check the consistency
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdc1

#Resize the file system, finally
sudo resize2fs /dev/sdc1

#Remount the disk
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /data #or whatever you want to call it

#Check to make sure it worked
df -h
```

It looks (and is) a bit scary, but it only takes a couple of minutes.  I'd recommend backing up your disk first.